# Simple script to test word expansion and pathname expansion

Tags: bash

I am trying to verify the following which I read [here](https://effective-shell.com/part-6-advanced-techniques/understanding-shell-expansion/):

> It is important to remember that the shell performs all of the types of expansion that we have described in order. This means that word expansion is performed before pathname expansion. So if you loop through the results of an expanded path, word splitting will not be performed on those results.

I wrote a very simple script I am using to verify the above quote about the order of operations of word and and pathname expansion:

```
$ cat test.sh
for path in /home/john/Downloads/*.xlsx

do
    echo "${path}"
done
```

The result

```
$ ./test.sh
/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx
/home/john/Downloads/x y.xlsx
```

From what I read, word expansion happens before path expansion, and they used a script very similar to this to demonstrate it.  But I actually don't understand how this example demonstrates it?  As far as I can see, "path" is a variable, and after the variable identifies a path, that will be $path.  So where an earth would word expansion ever come into this, since I can't see any words that would be considered for expansion.

To clarify, if we run over the first iteration, $path is empty until it checks "/home/john/Downloads/*.xlsx", at which point then it gets defined as "/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx" since this is the first entry.  At which point $path has been defined.  There was no opportunity for it to have word expansion applied (like, are they saying word-expansion gets applied to "null" before the actual path name defines the first result)?

Comment: https://effective-shell.com/part-6-advanced-techniques/understanding-shell-expansion/ under the heading "Pathname Expansion" right at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the authors wrote *word expansion*, a term that they don't use anywhere else on the page (but one that I was informed is indeed perfectly correct, see the POSIX specs [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06)), they seemed to have been referring to the split operation, what they refer to as "word splitting". This is the process whereby the shell will split things on the value of the `$IFS` variable (normally set to space, tab and newline). For example, consider this script (taken from [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), which is a great reference and I strongly urge you to read it):

```
#!/bin/sh -
printf "%d args:" "$#"
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf " <%s>" "$@"
echo
```

The script will simply print out its arguments, showing how they are split into words. Try running with different input:

```
$ foo.sh apple orange "passion fruit"
3 args: <apple> <orange> <passion fruit>
```

Here, the string `apple orange "passion fruit"` was split into the three "words" `apple`, `orange` and `passion fruit`. This is word splitting. Note how the quotes protected `passion fruit` from being split.

Now, as the article states, the order matters. If you read the "Expansion" section of the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), you will find:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

The relevant bit here is that word splitting, what I showed above, happens before filename (path) expansion. Your misconception is here:

> To clarify, if we run over the first iteration, $path is empty until it checks "/home/john/Downloads/*.xlsx", at which point then it gets defined as "/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx" since this is the first entry. At which point $path has been defined.

No, `$path` is already defined at that point, it isn't expanded to `/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx` inside the loop, but before the loop begins. We can break down the two, word splitting and pathname expansion, using a slightly different script to what you have:

```
#!/bin/bash

words="x y.xlsx *.xlsx"
for word in $words; do
  echo "word is '$word'"
done
```

Try that script in a directory with the following contents:

```
$ ls -1
CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx
'x y.xlsx'
```

The output is:

```
$ foo.sh
word is 'x'
word is 'y.xlsx'
word is 'CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx'
word is 'x y.xlsx'
```

So what is going on?

1. The variable `$words` is **split** into words on the value of `$IFS`. This results in 3 words: `z`, `y.xlsx` and `*.xlsx`.
2. Next, each of the three words undergoes path expansion. This leaves `x` and `y.xlsx` unchanged since they cannot be expanded to a path, but `*.xlsx` becomes `x y.xlsx` and `CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx`.

The point the authors are trying to make is that because word splitting has already occurred by the time the shell expands `*.xlsx` to  `x y.xlsx` and `CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx`, no further word splitting occurs and `x y.xlsx` is treated as a single word, despite containing a space.

---

Please note that the first version of this answer was wrong because I was confusing [tokenization](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) with word splitting.

Comment: There's a [whole section dedicated to *word expansions* in  the POSIX specification of the sh language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06). It usually refers to parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion.

Comment: In your first example, there is no word splitting because there's no unquoted word expansion. The fact that *the string `apple orange tomato` was split into the three words apple, orange and tomato* has nothing to do with $IFS or word splitting. You're confusing word splitting and shell syntax tokenisation.

Comment: Ah I was hoping you'd chime in here, @StéphaneChazelas, I had a feeling I was confusing something. Thanks, I made a minor edit for the word splitting, and will try and fix the rest tomorrow as I don't have time now.

Comment: @johnsmith please see the comment by Stéphane above. I had a pretty important misunderstanding here which I will try and correct tomorrow.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks again; I think it should be OK now.

Comment: @johnsmith please make sure to read the updated answer. I had a couple of serious mistakes in the version you accepted.

Comment: No, again word splitting is a (weird and anachronistic) feature that is triggered when there are unquoted word expansions (often useful for command substitution, rarely for parameter expansion especially with shells that have arrays and never for arithmetic expansion).  For it to happen, you need such an expansion, as in `var1='foo,/???,bar baz'  var2='a,b' IFS=,2; foo.sh 'foo, bar' $var1 $(echo "$var2,123") $((11 * 11))`. Where the shell identifies that last command as a `foo.sh` simple command with 5 tokens (not all of the spaces separate tokens, that's no splitting), and some go through ws.

Comment: Even though POSIX uses the term "word expansion", it's not at all correctly used in source here. The whole sentence is _"This means that word expansion is performed before pathname expansion."_, which doesn't make any sense when POSIX defines "word expansion" as an umbrella term that includes pathname expansion. They're trying to say "word splitting" there, but have made a mistake, with the result being near-nonsense, plain and simple. Worse, the mistake there is probably cause of a lot the confusion @johnsmith is experiencing here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas so https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting is wrong? Is `printf " <%s>" "$@"` or, more precisely, the process that populates `$@`, not an example of word splitting?

Comment: @terdon, `"$@"` is a very special case and doesn't involve $IFS. You'll find I'm one of the latest editors of that page. There are still a few confusions about word splitting in that wiki, but I've not gone round to fixing them.

Comment: Sorry my bad, as @ilkkachu says, "word expansion" in POSIX doesn't refer to cmdsubst, param/arith expansion only (the ones subject to IFS-splitting). The bash manual refers to "word expansion" in several places without ever defining it and with different meaning each time.

Comment: Yes I had seen you had edited it, @StéphaneChazelas, which is a large part of why I consider it reliable :) I always thought IFS was involved in populating `$@` though, so thanks for correcting me on that one too! I will try and find some way of demonstrating actual word splitting. Sigh...

Comment: Strictly speaking, in ash-based, pdksh and zsh shells at least, `$@` like `$*` contains the positional parameters joined with the first character of `$IFS`, but when used quoted and in list context, `"$@"` is split into the individual positional parameters regardless of the value of `$IFS`. That can be seen as a form of word splitting but it's a very special case which doesn't involve IFS. See `sh -c 'IFS=:; a=$@; echo "$a"' sh a b` with various shells for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what they're trying to explain is that after the shell expanded `/home/john/Downloads/*.xlsx` to `/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx` and
`/home/john/Downloads/x y.xlsx` ("pathname expansion"), it did not try to split it again into `/home/john/Downloads/CCIE-Collaboration-v3-Learning-Matrix.xlsx`,
`/home/john/Downloads/x` and `y.xlsx` ("word splitting" - *not* "word expansion"). All this is before the `for` loop starts assigning values to the variable. So the loop only iterates over two values instead of the three we would have seen if word splitting were to be performed on the result of pathname expansion. None of this is about what's going on inside the loop body.

On the other hand, if you had `for i in $(echo a b c)`, then the shell would do word splitting on the result of the command substitution, and you'd see three loop iterations instead of the one you'd get from `for i in "$(echo a b c)"`.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *"This means that word expansion is performed before pathname expansion."* in the quote there is meaningless, since the source never defines what "word expansion" is supposed to be. In the next sentence, they mention word splitting instead, which is described earlier in the page and is probably what they meant. So, **ignore the phrase "word expansion", it's wrong in that context, plain and simple**.

The next sentence of the quote makes more sense:

> So if you loop through the results of an expanded path, word splitting will not be performed on those results.

Consider the following, we create the two files `oneword` and `two words` in an empty directory, and loop over `./*`:

```
touch 'oneword' 'two words'
i=0 
for f in ./*; do
    printf "%d: %s\n" "$i" "$f"
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

The output is as follows, showing that the loop iterated over the two items `./oneword`, `./two words`, those being the direct results of the pathname expansion, and the latter filename was not further split.

```
0: ./oneword
1: ./two words
```

If word splitting happened *after* pathname expansion, that second file name would be split further into `./two` `words`, and the loop would run a total of three times. (Assuming the default `IFS`.)

---

The Q above continues with

> From what I read, word expansion happens before path expansion, and they used a script very similar to this to demonstrate it.

But as mentioned above, this is meaningless. The source you refer to does not define what "word expansion" means to them, and it's unclear what you mean with the phrase. It's not your fault: you're being confused by a source that can't keep its terminology in line.

Now, technically, the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) uses the phrase "word expansion" for all of tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, field splitting (often called word splitting), pathname/filename expansion and quote removal. But the context your source is using the phrase in does not make sense with that definition. Word expansion cannot happen "before" path expansion, since word expansion *includes* path expansion.

> So where an earth would word expansion ever come into this, since I can't see any words that would be considered for expansion.

Again, depends on what you mean. The POSIX sense of "word splitting" includes pretty much everything, so in the script in the Q, there's the "word expansion" (pathname expansion) of `/home/john/Downloads/*.xlsx` into the filenames, and the "word expansion" (parameter expansion) of `"${path}"` into the current value of the variable `path`. (And my script above also has a case of arithmetic expansion.)